# Setting RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I set the RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT to LinearLayout in code? I have a RelativeLayout which child is LinearLayout and I need to set the RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT in the child LinearLayout instance. The problem is that when I set it, I will lose the child LinearLayout parameters (I will lose the weight). My understanding is that the only way to set the RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT to child element is to use RelativeLayout.Layoutparams when setting the child view layout parameters.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Please post your xml. It will be a lot easier to understand what you have/want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the width height parms and weight along with your aligh left rule in programtically

```
layoutparms = new LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, weightthere);

   layoutparms.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, leftisdeview);
yourview.setLayoutParams(layoutparms);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to give `android:gravity="left"` to the parent linear layout.Remember that it is gravity not layout_gravity.